# '504 Gateway timeout error' on IPFS after I generate CID

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I am currently just trying to upload a file to IPFS which I think I have been able to do as it successfully returns a CID for the file. However, when I then go to `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<CID>` I then always get a `504 Gateway timeout error` every time and I have no clue if the upload has actually been successful as I can never see the file on IPFS.

This is the console output when I run the code:

```
{
  path: 'QmPcfLB9UPsJzh2LhACjiyWc4odWJFh9DhkxAN4UbjGxeu',
  cid: CID(QmPcfLB9UPsJzh2LhACjiyWc4odWJFh9DhkxAN4UbjGxeu),
  size: 119540,
  mode: 420,
  mtime: undefined
}
```

The code:

```js
module.exports.createSBT_post = async (req, res) => {
        const IPFS = await import('ipfs');
        const node = await IPFS.create();

        let { name, imageResult, description, grade, awardingBody, city, country, website }  = req.body;

        const imgBuf = Buffer.from(imageResult);

        const imgResults = await node.add(imgBuf);
        console.log(imgResults);

        const metadata = {
            "name": name,
            "description": description,
            "awardingBody": awardingBody,
            "city": city,
            "country": country,
            "website": website
        }

        const metadataJSON = JSON.stringify(metadata);
        const results = await node.add(metadataJSON);

        console.log(results.cid.toString());
};
```

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong and whenever I try and find an answer online the code/examples are always outdated and the ipfs documentation is of very little help. Please can someone explain as to why I can never view my files on IPFS once they have been uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit [an IPFS HTTP gateway and use it to download your images](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/):

- Instead of: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/someContentID
- Visit: https://someContentID.ipfs.4everland.io for example

Also keep in mind IPFS can be slow to replicate - it seems to take about 10 mins when using some of the slower services.

I use Pinata's HTTP Gateway, and here's your image: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmPcfLB9UPsJzh2LhACjiyWc4odWJFh9DhkxAN4UbjGxeu